# Optional Post Code is Not Working

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I have fresh install Magento 1.8.1.0, I set some countries to not required to enter post code on checkout page, the "*" sign is not display in frontend for those selected countries.

But After I clicked Continue without entering post code, I still get the javascript pop up alert saying ""Zip/Postal Code" is a required value."

[image]

I tried to change the post code field to

```
<label for="billing:postcode"><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" name="billing[postcode]" id="billing:postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>" class="input-text" />
</div>
```

But I still get pop up alert.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next try, with the correct error message. This error comes from here:

```
\Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data_Text::validateValue
if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && empty($value)) {
    $errors[] = Mage::helper('eav')->__('"%s" is a required value.', $label);
}
```

And the part `$attribute->getIsRequired()` is true, if the column `is_required` in `eav_attribute = 1`.

To change this, you should write an data update script and change the attribute. A description can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420199/magento-module-setup-change-product-attribute-to-not-required

```
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product','short_description','is_required',0);
```

## Wrong part

This is no magento standard behaviour.

If your input doesn't containt `class="required"`, there is no JS-error raised. So whatever theme you use, check this.

The error is raised here:

```
\Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract::validate
$_havingOptionalZip = Mage::helper('directory')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip();
if (!in_array($this->getCountryId(), $_havingOptionalZip)
    && !Zend_Validate::is($this->getPostcode(), 'NotEmpty')
) {
    $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the zip/postal code.');
}
```

Comment: Actually, it uses default theme, and it is fresh install and only one extension installed there. I will check if the extension makes this problem.

Comment: Are you sure it is a JS error? Ah damn it. This is no JS error, this error is thrown thorugh the AJAX request. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks Fabian for your help. I have commented above code in your answer, but still not works. I also check `Mage::helper('directory')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip();`, and the countries are exist, even my selected country in checkout page is exist. The error is not `Please enter the zip/postal code.` but `"Zip/Postal Code" is a required value.`. I edited my question, screenshot added. I think many people have the same problem. I searched on Google, but still not find the solution or the cause of this problem.

Comment: Please check if eav_attribute -> postcode is_required = 1 updated the answer.

Comment: Oh yeah... Thanks Fabian, this solved the problem, I changed it to 0 directly from DB. Can I change it from backend? Is there any configuration in backend to do this? I didn't found it in backend.

Comment: No there is not the (better) alternative to do this in the db is to write a update script. as described above. The problem with the "direct in the DB" is, that you can't reproduce it on the other environments an manual steps while deploying are horrible things you want to kill :-) Because we make mistakes all the time and not doing something (because it is done automatically) decreases the error rate :D

Answer (score 0):

I think this article may be helpful for you: http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/fixed-optional-postal-code-working/

Comment: Single link answers are not the best. Give more details about what can be found at that url. Read this for more details: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer